# How to kill a Boneleaf in D&D 3.5?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters

The Boneleaf is a monster in Heroes of Horror, D&D 3.5 page 143. The creature that the party generally encounters is actually a part of a much larger, subteranean monster that has 1D6+6 other similar outcroppings above ground.

To quote Heroes of Horror:

> A boneleaf functions as an independent
>   creature, but it is only a portion of a much larger
>   whole. While boneleaves are encountered singly, they are not
>   actually alone. If boneleaves are present in a given area, there
>   are always 1d6+6 of them in the region. They are considered
>   solitary creatures because each boneleaf in the group remains
>   anywhere from 100 yards to a mile away from its nearest fellow.
>   All the boneleaves in a group are in fact portions of the
>   same creature, connected by miles
>   of underground nerves.
>   Anything one boneleaf
>   experiences is known
>   to all of them, so characters
>   who encounter a
>   second boneleaf after defeating
>   the first will find it anticipates
>   their tactics and abilities.

The monster is a large aberation, with a CR of 6. Even though it is not a plant, it has some plantlike features. Another quote from HoH:

> Although a boneleaf
>   is not a plant, it has many traits
>   also possessed by plants. A boneleaf
>   is immune to magical sleep
>   effects, paralysis, stunning, and
>   mind-affecting spells and abilities
>   (charms, compulsions, phantasms,
>   patterns, and morale effects). It
>   has some fortifi cation against
>   critical hits; 50% of all critical hits
>   function as normal strikes.
>    Boneleaves so closely resemble
>   plants that a character must make a
>   DC 15 Spot check to realize the boneleaf
>   is anything more than a normal copse;
>   failure indicates the character comes close
>   enough for the creature to attack
>   with its extended reach before he
>   suspects anything is amiss.

I am planning an encounter somewhat in advance, but expect that by the time the party will face their first Boneleaf as a group of 5 7th level players. The plan is that the party will face another creature more suited to their level, but as it reaches a certain HP threshold it will try to get away. If it succeeds, and the players decide to follow it, they will find the creature licking its wounds against a tree. If they approach it, they find out that this was an illusion made by the Boneleaf to lure them closer to it, and the battle with the boneleaf begins (and the first creature gets away). The party consists of one Wizard, one Rogue, one Dread Necromancer, one Barbarian and one Cleric. I plan to locate the 'real' monster beneath the village where the players will be residing for the duration of the adventure. It would seem that the entire monster itself has no stats, for as far as I can see at least. Only these above-ground outcroppings have a statblock, and there is nothing I can find about the creature itself.

Comment: Arthaban, aside from modifying the question so that is describes a specific scenario (as HeyICanChan suggested), could you add some of the monster's stats? Specifically, if it's a plant, or an evil undead for example, there are several spells and class abilities that'll help here (showing again that more details are needed - if you have a high class druid / cleric, access to scrying, flying companions which can scan an area quickly or the ability to summon earth elementals to follow the 'nerve network' underground - just to drop a few ideas...)

Comment: I'd just state why the boneleaf is problematic. Is it because it has no stats, and there isn't a clear way to kill it that is described in the books? It sure looks so, and if this is the reason it's not much what a party can do to kill it biut what kills it (so, a list of ways to destroy the world might be a bad answer, but "destroy the world is the only way" might be a good one, if proved that other thingss don't work).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You've misunderstood the description of the Boneleaf's organisation. There are no stats for the "real" creature under the ground because there is no such thing.

A Boneleaf is several individuals connected by miles-long nerves that run through the ground. It's [a distributed being](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pando_(tree)), not a central creature with appendages. Kill each individual above-ground Boneleaf and that's it—that's the whole creature dead.

For your plot, you will have to use a different creature that does have an underground part lurking under the ground, or you will just have to use an extra-nasty Boneleaf individual that's under the village for some reason.

Comment: Thank you. I will be fine with not having a creature beneath the village at all, as that was not the main plot of the adventure, rather something I came up with upon reading the description of the Boneleaf. Upon re-reading the description, I have to agree with what you said. Thanks again.